# mysql update one table with second table ids

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I've got two tables

Here's a jsfiddle sample http://jsfiddle.net/tiitremmel/zW7bX/

There's two tables and result table.

To do it with `SELECT` is simple, but how to do it with `UPDATE`?

Comment: ,What the result you are execting. can you pls explain what you are trying to do ?

Comment: i need to add second tables id's to first table 'bid' column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update table1 t1
set bid = (select id from table2 t2 where t1.bd = t2.bd);
```

Is this the kind of thing you're after?